# Why don't drupal 7 allow the taxonomy's term fields?

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy

For content types, I am able to translate the content's fields in drupal, but for the taxonomies term's fields, its only allow to translate the title and body fields.I added two more fields in taxonomy's term. Please guide me.
[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the vocabulary setting a bit and then you will be able to do it. [image]

You need to select the option "Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated." (highlighted in above image) and then it will allow you to use a different term in each language with the translated terms field values. We are using this and its working fine. Though, other settings won't allow you to achieve what are you trying to do.

Hope that help!